# Lt-Spice doesn't give me all the information

Tags: ltspice

Here is my LT-spice simulation of a simple circuit.

[image]

I need to find the voltage across R6, but Lt-Spice doesn't give me that information.

Does anybody know why this is or if there is something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there. It is one of the voltage nodes relative to ground so it is not associated with any one component.